# Chars referenced by octal values in *NIX shell scripts -- getting them to be parsed?

Tags: unix, unix-shell

I have a script which absolutely 100% _has_ to be done in this ridiculous fashion:

echo $'\150\151\073\145\143\150\157' $'\171\141\171'

(unencoded: echo hi;echo yay)

The problem is that everything after the echo is assumed to be an argument, so the semi-colon and the second echo command are output as well.  Is there any way to get the shell to actually parse the semi-colon and break up the two commands?

Answer (score 1):

you could try with a NULL character just before the '\073':

```
echo $'\150\151\0\073\145\143\150\157' $'\171\141\171
```

this way the shell will parse the ';'

the output will be:

```
hi yay
```

and not

```
hi
yay
```

Answer (score 0):

`eval`?  Backticks?  Pressing enter between each line?  `sh -c`?  `$()`?  Something else entirely?  Without knowing *why* you have to do it in this ass-backwards way, we can't really offer many alternatives, since we don't know what you *can* use.

Answer (score 0):

It's not letting me reply to comments since I'm not logged in.

Anyhow, everything must be input on one line with octal characters.  No `, no $(, no enters, and no eval.  It's octal or nothing.

Answer (score 0):

... nor can I edit previous messages.

I've tried the null bytes, but it just terminates that string -- not the echo command.  Your example would not result in two separate commands but a single command.  It's the two commands I'm after.